# How to get working Firefox bookmarks scope?

Tags: unity, firefox, unity-dash, scopes

I upgraded to Ubuntu 13.10, and saw that there is now a package "unity-scope-firefoxbookmarks", and I see in the dash sources list:

[image: Firefox Bookmarks Scope]

However, I cannot find any of my bookmarks from the dash (the source button is always off).

There is something to enable, or a service to start in order to indice bookmarks?

Answer (score 1):

I found the answer: I only had to enable the "Web" category on the result filter panel of the dash, it was not enabled by default (see screenshot below).

[image: Enable Web category sources]